# For and Foreach Loops Print Multiple Results

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, for-loop, foreach, strtotime

This is result that I want:

```
January 2018  
Division A  
Division B  
Division C  

February 2018
Division A  
Division B  
Division C  

..so on..
```

In controller, this is the code:

```
$i = 0;
for ($dd = $start_date; $dd <= $last_date;) {

    $month_iteration = date("F Y",strtotime($dd));
    $data['months'][$i] = $month_iteration; // this successfully saves months in months array

    $dd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dd . 'next month')); // ctr++
    $i++;
}

foreach ($data['months'] as $m_key) { // for every month saved, I need to print all divisions
    $data['months'][$m_key]['divisions'] = $this->division_model->get_divisions();
}
```

Usually it works fine when I use foreach inside foreach inside foreach. In this case, I'm not sure how to save months in array other than using for loop.

With above code, it resulting:

```
January 2018
error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
February 2018
error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Array
Division A Division B Division C
Array
Division A Division B Division C
```

So it prints months and divisions separately and multiply (?)

I have tried save divisions in for loop with this code:

```
$data['months'][$i]['divisions'] = $this->division_model->get_divisions();
```

When I do `var_dump($data)` divisions doesn't show anything. I understand that I also wrong using this approach.

What do I do wrong? What is the best approach to meet the result needed?

Comment: provide example of $start_date and $end_date and a `print_r($this->division_model->get_divisions())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will help you .

```
$weeks['start_date'] = '2018/01/01';
$weeks['end_date'] = '2018/08/01';
$daterange = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($weeks['start_date']), new DateInterval('P1M'), new DateTime($weeks['end_date']));
$weekDayList = array();
foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $weekDayList[$date->format("F Y")]['divisions'] =  ['division1','division2','division3'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($weekDayList);
```

if this is what you are looking for
result::

```
Array
(
    [January 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

    [February 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

    [March 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

    [April 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

    [May 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

    [June 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

    [July 2018] => Array
        (
            [divisions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => division1
                    [1] => division2
                    [2] => division3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me got closer to result. Nevertheless I modified a bit to send months arrays and divisions arrays to view. :D